# Can the lines of code be reduced in this vb.net code?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have the following code, my employer wants me to **reduce the lines of code** to do the job.

```
Private Function getClientSheetNames(Optional ByVal type As String = "all") As List(Of String)
    If type = "extra" Then
        Return clientExtraSheetNames
    End If
    Dim prev, curr As New List(Of String)
    For Each name In clientMonthlySheetNames
        curr.Add(name + " (" + currMonth + ")")
    Next name
    If type = "currMonth" Then
        Return curr
    End If
    For i = 1 To clientMonthlySheetNames.Count - 1
        prev.Add(clientMonthlySheetNames(i) + " (" + prevMonth + ")")
    Next
    If type = "prevMonth" Then
        Return prev
    End If
    If type = "monthly" Then
        Return curr.Union(prev).ToList
    End If
    Return clientExtraSheetNames.Union(curr.Union(prev)).ToList
End Function

Private Function getDevSheetNames(Optional ByVal type As String = "all") As List(Of String)
    If type = "extra" Then
        Return devExtraSheetNames
    End If
    Dim sheetNames, prev, curr As New List(Of String)
    For Each name In devMonthlySheetNames
        curr.Add(name + " (" + currMonth + ")")
    Next name
    If type = "currMonth" Then
        Return curr
    End If
    For Each name In devMonthlySheetNames
        prev.Add(name + " (" + prevMonth + ")")
    Next name
    If type = "prevMonth" Then
        Return prev
    End If
    If type = "monthly" Then
        Return curr.Union(prev).ToList
    End If
    sheetNames.Add(devExtraSheetNames(0))
    sheetNames.AddRange(curr.Union(prev).ToList)
    sheetNames.AddRange(devExtraSheetNames.GetRange(1, devExtraSheetNames.Count - 1))
    Return sheetNames
End Function
```

I am not able to make out how can I cut the lines and have the same functionality !

**Are there any vb.net construct that can reduce the loc by better implementation ?**

**Can I have a new function to be called from getClientSheetNames and getDevSheetNames that will can implement code resue ?**

**Can I introduce polymorphism in a possible new function ?**

Any performance improvements are most welcome !

Please help !!

Comment: "my employer wants me to reduce the lines of code to do the job." - Why?

Comment: Well, I don't know !! He thinks that I have done a very bad implementation, so If I reduce the LOC I will actually improve on the logic.

Comment: improving the logic is a slightly different (and more important) requirement to reducing the lines of code (although sometimes related)

Comment: He means the latter one.. anyways contribute how you can help ?

Comment: I think you'll find he means the former.

Comment: Contribute what you have.. I may convince him.. over the new implementation !

Comment: Just add ":" at the end of every line and make it into one insanely long single line piece of code. That'll teach 'em. On a serious note, you do realize that by including multiple variables on the same Dim line, they are going to be of type variable, right? I was also going to suggest you turn off screenupdating, but oops! that would be 2 more lines of code :p  Good luck, my friend!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function should do one thing.  Both of those functions do five separate, unrelated tasks.  Draw a flowchart and you'll see you almost end up with five distinct functions.  So split each function into five individual functions.

```
Function getAllClientSheetNames() As List(Of String)
Function getExtraClientSheetNames() As List(Of String)
Function getCurrentMonthClientSheetNames() As List(Of String)
Function getPreviousMonthClientSheetNames() As List(Of String)
Function getMonthlyClientSheetNames() As List(Of String)
```

The most they correlate is that `getAll~` includes both `getCurrentMonth~` and `getPreviousMonth~`, which you can call from `getAll~`.

This will improve logic and readability.  It may (no gaurantees) even reduce your LoC.

Comment: Well, that I agree.. but I want to keep it logically 1 function to get the sheetNames. I don't want to fiddle with 3-4 functions just to get my sheetNames. Keeping them in 1 function is intended to be logically 1 entity !

Comment: I fail to see your logic.  Your one function doesn't do one thing, it does several independant things.  By keeping it in one function, you're more likely to do damage with code changes then if they're separate.

Comment: What code do you run if type is "prevMonth"? I think you spend time building the curr array that you don't use. I agree with @Hand. Your code is unclear and inefficient. Don't fear separate functions, they do actually help if you name them well.

Comment: Ok... I will try seperating them.. !!
Meanwhile can you suggest improvements in this code.. that will automatically reflect in my new code with seperated functions !

Comment: I just want to throw up my hand and agree. Single-responsiblity is a powerful and smart way of thinking. The code is already too convoluted. And you should have the confidence as a programmer to tell your boss how less lines of code does not mean it'll be faster, or better in any way.

Comment: Considering just one piece of function, for example  Dim prev, curr As New List(Of String)
    For Each name In clientMonthlySheetNames
        curr.Add(name + " (" + currMonth + ")") If that's what you need to do then I don't see how to speed it up. By doing only the processing you need you will get some improvement, but otherwise any improvement would need to come from some overall design change.
    Next name
    If type = "currMonth" Then
        Return curr
    End If

Comment: Thanks for your views guys !
I managed to cut make a function addMonth(list, month) and substituted in the above code and made my boss happy.. It was possible.. as it seems obvious now.

Comment: Glad to help!  Don't worry, I look at the code I wrote 5 years ago and shake my head in disgust.  I learned a lot about efficient and maintainable code through experience, and that good intentions like LoC, memory usage and optimization are a mostly waste of time.